# Get validation error message of array fields in laravel without displaying array key

Tags: validation, laravel-5, laravel-blade

I have an auto generated fields using jquery and my problem now is how to get error message without showing the index key. This is my code below:

```
@for($num = 0; $num < old('number', 1); $num++)
    <input type="text" class="form-control guest_name" name="last_name[]" id="last_name" placeholder="lastname" value="{{ old('last_name', ['',''])[$num+1] }}">
    @if ($errors->has('last_name' . ($num)))
        <div class="form-group">
            <p class="text-danger">{{ $errors->first('last_name' . ($num)) }}</p>
        </div>
    @endif
@endfor
```

This is my validation:

```
for($i=0; $i < count($this->request->get('last_name')); $i++){
    $rules['last_name'.$i] = ['required'];
}
return $rules;
```

And now, the validation message is like this:

```
last name0 is required.
```

How can I just display it as `last name is required.`?

Comment: You should be able to do the same loop for `$messages` (Validator has a 3rd param, array input, rules and messages), but I'm not sure how to do this with your current approach. Should be the same loop, but `$messages['last_name.'.$i.'.required'] = ['The last name field is required'];` so that each `last_name.*.required` key is set to the string `'The last name field ...'`. See if you can find that in the documentation for Validation.

Comment: Found it: https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/validation#customizing-the-error-messages (`public function messages()`, likely the same as `public function rules()`)

Comment: @TimLewis Thanks for the help, I'll check on this one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks everyone for the inputs, I'm able to do it this way, someone might need it someday.

**validation.php**

```
<?php
     $fields = ['last_name'];
     $_30 = [];

$return =[
    /*LANGUAGE LINES*/
    'attributes' => [
        'last_name' => 'Last Name',
    ];
];
foreach($fields as $field){
    for($i = 0; $i<30; $i++) {
        $return['attributes'][$field . $i] = $return['attributes'][$field];
    }
}

return $return;
```